# How To translate text in C# winforms

Tags: c#, translation, google-translate

I need to translate some text & i am trying to use google translator to translate it. I checked this [article](http://martinnormark.com/translate-text-in-c-using-google-translate). But i am getting an exception in following code.

```
result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

*Exception:The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Large.*

I have never Used APIs so was trying to use this class to translate the text.

Any suggestions ?

I have checked the similar posts but could not find simpler way to do    that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some SDKs for that.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/ (Unofficial Google Translate API - Seem old)

http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/ (Microsoft Translator API - Commercial)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512419.aspx (Microsoft Translator API guide)

You can download the source codes and read them

Comment: I have tried this, it gives another exception **failed to get response**

Comment: Heard That Google API is not free anymore. is it true?

Comment: Some of Google Apis are free, others isn't free anymore

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Winforms, [Microsofts Translator](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/) is also a good option, they're provided as webservices which are very easy to use in .net.

Documentation:

- [Updated documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx)

Comment: Yes, i m using winforms.Any tutorial on how to use it?

Comment: Microsofts API documentation is a bit of a mess at the moment, they changed their authentication to Azure a month ago but haven't updated all their documentation.