# Translation using transaltion class json property

Tags: c#

I have translate class store language code

```
public class translate
{
    [JsonProperty("fr")]
    public string fr { get; set; }
}
```

How we translate given string is any idea using above class how to translate English to French
I can not use api I am only using unicode like above
Please help

Comment: I'm afraid I'm finding it very hard to understand your question at the moment. It would help readability if you'd use real code rather than pseudocode (C# is case-sensitive) and follow .NET naming conventions. Please give an example of your data, and what you're expecting to do with it.... at the moment it's unclear to me whether you're asking for help using a translation API, or whether you're expecting to *create* some kind of translation API given data in multiple languages.

Comment: You cannot translate directly. Defining JSON property on top of the variable will not translate content itself. You might need to look into the answer of the following. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238733/how-to-translate-text-in-c-sharp-winforms